# cordova can't play audio on android 4.x

Tags: android, html, cordova, audio

I build a cocos2d game project , and build on Android .It cant play audio on Android . but can play audio on iOS and browser .

i catched some error like this via adb logcat .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGMM5.png)

my cordova version : 6.x

and android os version 4.4

So anybody know how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Some code would be nice. If you´r using the Cordova media plugin you have to use absolute route to your media file like: /android_asset/www/.

Comment: Is this HTML5 Audio?